# Get list of all Topics in use by a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query-variable

I have a custom post type that has an option to tag that post as part of a 'Topic'. This is set in the taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'topic',
    array('post','blog','shows'),
    array(
        'label' => __('Topics'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => 'topic',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'topic')
        ));
}
```

And I need a way to get a list of all topics in use by the 'Shows' post type, but I cannot figure out how to do this!

I think it would be something like:

```
 <?php  $topics = get_query_var( 'topic' );  ?>
```

but that obviously isn't working. If anyone has suggestions, I would really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I cracked it actually! Used this snippet:

```
<?php 
  $custom_terms = get_terms('topic');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'episodes',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topic',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
        ),
    ),
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';


 }
}
?>
```